# WPS Office "Export List" function: does Microsoft Excel have this feature?

Tags: excel, filter, export, autofilter, wps

[WPS Office Export List function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbXwY.png)

WPS has this very handy function called "Export List" (it's only available in their premium package); when you autofilter a specific column and click the "Export button", it will produce a new worksheet that contains a table indicating the item names (i.e. Label) and the corresponding times it showed up in the column (i.e. Count)

Does Microsoft Excel have this same function or none? if yes, how will I do it? :(

I tried searching for Microsoft Excel add-ins and formulas that can do the same function but I can't find anything online :(

any help will be greatly appreciated

[Excel has no Export List function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsOXL.png)

Comment: If you copy a filtered table to the clipboard, and then paste it into a new tab or worksheet, only the visible rows will be included and the resulting rows will be renumbered.